# How to accurately estimate the time remaining in a PC/Laptop battery?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, battery

I am making a C++ program on Windows in Visual Studio 2017. I want this program to calculate how long the battery will last on the laptop/PC the program is running on. I want to make this program because I have realized the estimated time remaining on my laptop battery (the battery icon in the Taskbar) is not accurate.

What factors do I need to take into account to estimate the time remaining of the battery? Or, is there code to show the discharge/charging rate of the battery?

One of these factors I have identified that changes the remaining charge in the battery is screen brightness. Is there a way to find what the user has set the brightness to?

If you have the answer, please explain each step thoroughly so I can easily understand it, because I am not very familiar with this part of C++.

Comment: I agree with Irelia. You could get the percentage of battery charge, but you couldn't accurately estimate how long the battery is left to use. The power consumption of a battery is related to many factors, I suggest you could refer to the Doc: [Managing Battery Life and Power Consumption Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/managing-battery-life-and-power-consumption-overview-technicalreference?view=windows-11)

Comment: Making a prediction based on the observed depletion rate between different percentage lookups over time is probably the best you can do.

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned Visual Studio, I'm going to assume you're on Windows. The API to retrieve power of a pc/laptop is [GetSystemPowerStatus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getsystempowerstatus) which takes a pointer to and fills the [SYSTEM_POWER_STATUS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/ns-winbase-system_power_status) structure.

Example:

```
#include <windows.h>

int main(){
 SYSTEM_POWER_STATUS sps = {0};
 if(GetSystemPowerStatus(&sps)){
    //check the structure
 }
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me so quickly. I already have this information in my program to get the battery per cent and time remaining of battery charge from what the computer has calculated, but I want to calculate the remaining time myself. So is there a way to get the average rate of how fast the battery charge is depleting so I can then roughly get the estimated time left with that information?

Comment: Getting accurate estimate depends on many factors, like which processes are running, how much charge each task/thread uses, and overall percentage drain.

Comment: @coo What's the specific reason that you wish to confuse your users? By rolling your own, all you're really accomplishing is producing a value that's different from the value displayed in other parts of Windows' UI. Which value is the user supposed to trust now? Chances are that they will not trust either one going forward. A lose-lose situation.

Comment: @llnspectable The program is more for me because I do not trust the estimate that the computer gives, and I wanted to see if I could make a better version for my own use.  Another thing I wanted to add to my program was a pop-up low charge notification. Because for many years my laptop would run out of charge and not warn me about the low charge before it dies. Which really annoys me.

Comment: @Irelia is there a way to find how much charge each task uses or the overall percentage drain?

Comment: @coo If the hardware reports wrong values then there's nothing you can do about it. This is a problem your OEM needs to fix, if your batteries are genuine parts. If they are not, replace them with genuine parts.